# Input string not in correct format to parse into DateTime

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, datetime

I am facing problem while converting DataTime into Time on 12 hour clock machine. Following code works fine on 24 Hour clock machine.

```
(new DisplayReminder(_name, _displayText, _snoozTime, TimeSpan.Parse(_startTime.ToShortTimeString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).Show();
```

`TimeSpan.Parse(_startTime.ToShortTimeString()` throws exeception that input string not in correct format, here I am trying to get time part from DateTime value `_startDate`
Any suggestion or solution on this problem.

Comment: It's probably because of the AM/PM text, which is not really applicable in a timespan I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but just getting the time of day shouldn't involve string conversions:

```
TimeSpan time = _stateTime.TimeOfDay;
```

I'd strongly advise you to avoid string conversions unless they're *inherently* part of what you're trying to achieve.

Personally I don't like using `TimeSpan` as a time of day anyway, but that's the BCL for you. You might want to also look into my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library which has a clearer separation of various date/time concepts.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar: Base Class Library. Basically ".NET libraries out of the box" (not *strictly* accurate, but close enough for now).

Comment: Thanku again for knowledgeable replies, I check out Noda Times library, download it and use it but I am unable to use it exactly what is meant to be. But this solution works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(
         _startTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss"), "hh:mm:ss",
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it will format your date to same format as `TimeSpan.ParseExact` accepts, so it will run on any machine (I assume that _startTime is `DateTime`)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
startTime.TimeOfDay.ToString()
```

Comment: What? You already have a timespan from TimeOfDay, why convert it to string and then convert it back, only to convert it to a string again?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that it works fine when 24H but crushes in 12H system, BECAUSE of the "PM" "AM" part ! get rid of it you'll be safe
`11:54:33` PM and `23:54:33` are VERY different in terms of handling

**EDIT**
it might be not the best solution but it works if you cut the last indexes of the string:

```
    int index = _StartTime.IndexOf("M");
    if (index >= 0) 
{
_StartTime = _StartTime.Substring(0, index-1);
switch (_StartTime.IndexOf("P"))
case : -1
 _StartTime = _StartTime.Substring(0,_StartTime.Length);
 break;

default:
 string hours = _startTime.Substring(_StartTime.Length-8,2);
 int H = Convert.ToInt32(hours);
 H += 12;
 string result = _StartTime.Substring(0, _StartTime.Length-8)+ Convert.ToString(H)+_startTime.Substring(_StartTime.Length-6);

_StartTime = result;
break;
}
```

this will throw AM/PM away, you can use the same previous code after this
**SECOND EDIT**
it's the most horrible solution but it works ;)

Comment: Ok, I got problem now, can u plz suggest solution on it?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar my answer allows you to parse `AM/PM` timespans

Comment: The other solutions are far better. Not only is this error prone if AM/PM is missing, you will actually get the incorrect time back if you just cut of the last part

Comment: @chouaib System time now coming `{29-11-2013 PM 12:59:00}` so this wont work.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar; What's wrong with the other solutions given?

Comment: @Patrick i mentioned that it might be not the best solution, but i am 100% sure that it is not wrong ;) can you prove it's wrong?

Comment: @chouaib: In your example for 23:54 I would expect the value of 11:54 PM to return a timespan with 23:54, not 11:54.

Comment: 11:54 PM returns 11:54 and 23:45 returns 23:54

Comment: And you edited your answer after my comment. It won't fail if AM/PM is missing now at least.

Comment: @chouaib: That's what I'm saying. Shouldn't it return 23:54?

Comment: yes @Patrick actually i edited it couple of times ;) my i idea is just to get rid of the AM/PM part no matter how to do it, i thought it doesn't matter but i will edit it again ;) ... wait

Comment: @Patrick Sorry I was busy in using Noda Time, try to understand what it is..!

Comment: @chouaib This is also very nice answer,but I wont able to mark other solution as Answer since Sir Jon Skeet answers my question!

Comment: @AnkushMadankar i agree with his answer as the solution for this question, thank you for giving credits to mine also ;)